# Override context language based on visitor's GEOIP in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, analytics, maxmind

I am using sitecore 7.5 version with mongo analytics db and I need to override the context language based on Visitor’s Geo IP .

but whenever I call my file on httpRequestBegin Pipeline, current `Sitecore.analytics.Tracker.Current` is null.

Can anyone please help, I really need to find solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

The tracker doesn't get built until the last processor of `httpRequestBegin` (`ExecuteRequest`).

Take a look at my blog post showing the sequence of events http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/a-sitecore-8-request-from-beginning-to.html

As you cans see, the `CreateTracker` pipeline is where the action happens. So your work either needs to occur after `ExecuteRequest` in `httpRequestBegin`, or if possible, in `Createtracker`

However, you should know that the Geo IP lookup doesn't necessarily happen immediately. The information might not show up until after the request has completed.

Another approach is to not use the Maxmind lookup that happens as part of DMS. Instead you could download the `Maxmind` database and do work yourself during the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline. Since you only need to identify the country, you can use the [free version](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/). That way, you don't need to involve the Tracker class.

Comment: I tried your first option and tried to call my language resolver file after ExecuteRequest process in HttpRequestBegin Pipeline, but still getting current tracker null.

But can you explain where to find CreateTracker Pipeline because i am unable to locate this pipeline in sitecore 7.5 all versions.

Thanks

Comment: The config is for `CreateTracker` is in  `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config`. If you still can't find it then that might indicate why the class is null.

Comment: Yes we have that file..but still getting null Tracker object. Do you have any other solution because I really need to resolve this?

Comment: My preferred option in my answer is to do a local DB lookup, and not use the Tracker object, as this is unreliable if you need the data immediately.